# How can I animate a scaling of the character mouth to simulate talking?

Tags: modeling, animation

I think scaling on the Y will be good simulation for talking but I'm not sure if only the Y and if only scaling or maybe also rotating and position ? The idea is to create some talking animation so I can use it later with unity3d.

[image: Character mouth]

Comment: do you mean you want to create a shape key and scale the mesh or do you have a bone for the mouth?

Comment: @moonboots The mesh. The object is not my own. I bought it from the assets store of unity : There are some details there : https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/3d/characters/humanoids/sci-fi/kid-from-space-66611

Comment: So if you don't want to use bones you need to use shapekeys, check some tutorials if you don't already know